# Restrict API Usage

Tags: javascript, rest, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to put a restriction on my API so only registered users can use it on their websites.  The `javascript` will be used on their website by pasting it into their `html`.  Right now I use a token for each user but it's visible to the public on their site so anyone could copy it.  It tracks usage but doesn't restrict it to only their site.

My first thought was to get the `HTTP_REFERER` variable from the http headers on the server and make sure it's from the domain registered by the user.  This won't work because `HTTP_REFERER` can be blank or changed.

My second thought was to use `JavaScript` in the pasted script to get the `document.location` and pass that back the to server.  That can also be tampered with so it is unreliable.

I'm looking at `OAUTH2` now as a solution.  I don't know much about it besides it's used for `SSO`. Looking at this JS OAUTH2 Lib too: https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso
Could they be used for what I need to do?

One requirement is that the script is pasted into the HTML. There shouldn't be any other configuration on their site that needs to be done.

What other solutions are their for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any other configuration on their site that needs to be done other than pasting your javascript ?

Well, then probably OAUTH2 is not what you are looking for, OAUTH adds the concept of an authorization server to your web API and  the complexity increases.

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

if you are not looking to authorize users but just identify domains that can consume your api from javascript, enable cors and add an attribute to specify which origins are allowed to access the resource. Example :

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Thanks.